# Search for string and get count in vi editor

Tags: search, count, vi

I want to search for a string and find the number of occurrences in a file using the vi editor.

Comment: The selected answer (`:g/xxxx/d`)is terrible, dangerous, and inferior to others on this page. Please unselect it.

Comment: i agree and it only tells you 'lines deleted' not 'occurrences deleted'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:g/xxxx/d
```

This will delete all the lines with pattern, and report how many deleted.  Undo to get them back after.

Comment: Of course, he can just omit the "d" so he doesn't have to unto the operation.

Comment: Note this only tells you how many lines - not how many occurences. I think dirk's is a better solution.

Comment: My solution below correctly counts multiple occurences within a line and there is nothing to undo.

Comment: Yup, doesn't do occurrences.

Comment: This can be quite slow for very large files.

Comment: Ugh, this is ugly and dangerous

Answer (score 222):

THE way is

:%s/pattern//gn

Comment: This is the most authentic answer with no over-kill trick used.

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: What if the pattern i want to search has spaces in betwee?

Answer (score 126):

You need the `n` flag. To count words use:

```
:%s/\i\+/&/gn
```

and a particular word:

```
:%s/the/&/gn
```

See [`count-items`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items) documentation section.

If you simply type in:

```
%s/pattern/pattern/g
```

then the status line will give you the number of matches in vi as well.

Comment: It looks like this answer is for Vim users and not for Vi :(

Comment: Do you only have vi on your system? Which version?

Comment: Someone tagged your quesiton with vim in it... I removed it.

Answer (score 43):

:%s/string/string/g
will give the answer.

Comment: What a better answer.  +5 if possible

Comment: I guess it would work only when no '.*' is used in the pattern

Comment: No need to repeat the string, just do `%s/string//ng`.

Answer (score 26):

(similar as Gustavo said, but additionally: )

For any *previously* search, you can do simply:

```
:%s///gn
```

A pattern is not needed, because it is already in the search-register (`@/`).

"%" - do `s/` in the whole file
"g" - search global (with multiple hits in one line)
"n" - prevents any replacement of `s/` -- **nothing is deleted!** nothing must be undone!
(see: `:help s_flag` for more informations)

(This way, it works perfectly with "*Search for visually selected text*", as described in [vim-wikia tip171](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text))

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:

> **:%s/string-to-be-searched//gn**

**For learning**:

There are 3 modes in VI editor as below
[image]

- `:` you are entering from `Command` to `Command-line` mode. Now, whatever you write after `:` is on CLI(Command Line Interface)
- `%s` specifies all lines. Specifying the range as `%` means do substitution in the entire file. Syntax for  all occurrences substitution is `:%s/old-text/new-text/g`
- `g` specifies all occurrences in the line. With the `g` flag , you can make the whole line to be substituted. If this `g` flag is not used then only first occurrence in the line only will be substituted.
- `n` specifies to output number of occurrences
- `//`double slash represents omission of `replacement text`. Because we just want to find.

Once got the number of occurrences, you can Press `N` Key to see occurrences one-by-one.

For finding and counting in particular range of line number 1 to 10:

> **:1,10s/hello//gn**

- Please note, `%` for whole file is repleaced by `,` separated line numbers.

For finding and replacing in particular range of line number 1 to 10:

> **:1,10s/helo/hello/gn**

Answer (score 3):

use

> :%s/pattern/\0/g

when pattern string is too long and you don't like to type it all again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing:

1. Search either with `*` to do a "bounded search" for what's under the cursor, or do a standard `/pattern` search.
2. Use `:%s///gn` to get the number of occurrences. Or you can use `:%s///n` to get the number of lines with occurrences.

****** I really with I could find a plug-in that would giving messaging of "match N of N<sub>1</sub> on N<sub>2</sub> lines" with every search, but alas.

Note:
Don't be confused by the tricky wording of the output. The former command might give you something like `4 matches on 3 lines` where the latter might give you `3 matches on 3 lines`. While *technically* accurate, the latter is misleading and should say '3 lines match'. So, as you can see, there really is never any need to use the latter ('n' only) form. You get the same info, more clearly, and more by using the 'gn' form.