# Using Vim, how do you use a variable to store count of patterns found?

Tags: vim

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715643/search-for-string-and-get-count-in-vi-editor) was helpful for getting a count of a certain pattern in Vim, but it would be useful to me to store the count and sum the results so I can echo a concise summary.

I'm teaching a class on basic HTML to some high schoolers, and I'm using this script to be quickly check numbers of required elements throughout all their pages without leaving Vim. It works fine, but when students have more than 10 `.html` files it gets cumbersome to add up the various sections by hand.

Something like:

```
img_sum = :bufdo %s/<img>//gen
```

would be nice. I think I'll write a ruby script to check the pages more thoroughly and check for structure, but for now I'm curious about how to do this in Vim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be solved by a counter separate from the one built-in into the
`:substitute` command: Use Vim-script variable to hold the number of pattern
matches.  A convenient way to register every match and modify a particular
variable accordingly, is to take advantage of the substitute with an
expression feature of the `:substitute` command (see `:help sub-replace-\=`).
The idea is to use a substitution that evaluates an expression increasing
a counter on every occurrence, and does not change the text it is operating
on.

The first part of the technique cannot be implemented straightforwardly
because it is forbidden to use Ex commands in expressions (including `\=`
substitute expressions), and therefore it is not possible to use the `:let`
command to modify a variable.  [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944828/254635) the question "[gVim find/replace
with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5942360/254635)", I have proposed a simple trick to overcome that limitation,
which is based on using a single-item list (or dictionary containing a single
key-value pair).  Since the `map()` function transforms a list or a dictionary
in place, that only item could be changed in a constrained expression context.
To do that, one should call the `map()` function passing an expression
evaluating to the new value along with the list containing the current value.

The second half of the technique is how to avoid changing text when using
a substitution command.  In order to achieve that, one can make the pattern
have zero-width by prepending `\ze` or by appending `\zs` atoms to it (see
`:help /\zs`, `:help /\ze`).  In such a way, the modified pattern captures
a string of zero width just before or after the occurrence of the initial
pattern.  So, if the replacement text is also empty, substitution does not
cause any change in the contents of a buffer.  To make the substitute
expression evaluate to an empty string, one can just extract an empty
substring or sublist from the resulting value of that expression.

The two ideas are put into action in the following command.

```
:let n=[0] | bufdo %s/pattern\zs/\=map(n,'v:val+1')[1:]/ge
```

Comment: Here's what I tried for <p> tags, but it didn't work:
`bufdo %s/\c<p>\ze//gen
let n=[0]|bufdo %s//\=map(n,'v:val+1')[1:]/gen
echo "number of <p> tags: " n[0] "\n"`

Comment: @labyrinth:  Do not use the `n` flag in this substitution command, since it orders Vim to ignore and not to evaluate the substitute part that does all the work!  Just use `:let n=[0] | bufdo %s/\c<p>\ze/\=map(n,'v:val+1')[1:]/ge`.

Comment: You can't use `:let`, but you can use `g:` dictionary: `bufdo %s/\c<p>\zs/\=[extend(g:, {'numptags': get(g:, 'numptags', 0)+1})][1:]/ge`.

Comment: @ZyX:  That is exactly what I said: to change a variable in expression you have to use functions modifying a list or a dictionary (since variables store that objects as references).  I have considered using the dictionary containing global variables, but that kind of a solution is neither simpler nor shorter.  And it has a disadvantage of necessity of polluting the globals namespace.  So, if one prefers to use a dictionary it is probably better to use a custom dictionary (similarly to the list example in the answer) instead of `g:`.  Anyway, thanks for the addition!

Comment: @ib. You are already polluting global namespace with `n`. If it is to be used from function, you can always replace `g:` with `l:`.

Comment: @ZyX:  Please be careful in wording: Whether the variable is in global namespace or not, depends on the context that command is run.  If it is inside a function, the global namespace is untouched.  Of course, one can use the `l:` dictionary of local variables, but it does not give any significant advantages over using a separate dictionary or a list (regardless of whether they are local or global variables).  Furthermore, in this case, dictionary solutions are a little more bloated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer above is hard to understand and more pretty way to use external command `grep` like this:

```
:let found=0
:bufdo let found=found+(system('grep "<p>" '.expand('%:p') . '| wc -l'))
:echo found
```